# Why doesn't build of net-snmp-5.7.2 provide /etc/rc.d/init.d/snmptrapd?

Tags: rhel6, rpm, net-snmp

I am packaging an RPM for RHEL6, built from `net-snmp-5.7.2.tar.gz`.  I see that the file `/etc/rc.d/init.d/snmpd` gets created and packaged but I do not see the init file for `/etc/rc.d/init.d/snmptrapd`.  Is `snmptrapd` depreciated?

Did I forget to pass the right switch to `./configure`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! There it is in the dist directory but it is called `snmptrapd-init.d`